# Could not validate web app name (Azure)

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying create a web app on Azure, but no matter what i name my URL, it always warn me that

> Could not validate web app name

What could have cause this problem? Any ideas that could fix this problem? thank you. I'm thinking about deploying my app on Winhost if the issue won't be solved (please hear me out, I've tried a lot of names here but it still says the samething).

[image]

Comment: maybe the web app name already exists?

Comment: How could somebody name their site like that? I mean I've even tried a lot of different names like the name above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the preview (i.e. BETA) portal. I have experienced lots of weirdness like this.  Try the old portal - [manage.windowsazure.com](https://manage.windowsazure.com)

Comment: Click on your profile link in top right corner, should open a dropdown with link to "Full Azure portal" at bottom.

Comment: It redirected me to the new portal.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this after deleting an API App to recreate on a new App Service Plan with the same name.

(In Chrome) I cleared storage for the site `https://portal.azure.com`, refreshed the page (F5), and the problem was immediately solved.